# ¿Un atributo de instancia puede tener el nombre de la clase?

Tags: java, lista, nodos, bluej

estaba viendo este código:

```
class NodeInt {
    int data;         
    NodeInt next;   
    
    /** Constructor A: crea un nodo con dato d y que no tiene
     *  siguiente.
     *  @param d int.
     */ 
    NodeInt(int d) { 
        this.data = d; 
        this.next = null; 
    }
    
    /** Constructor B: crea un nodo con un dato d, y con nodo 
     *  siguiente s.
     *  @param d int.
     *  @param s NodeInt.
     */ 
    NodeInt(int d, NodeInt s) { 
        this.data = d; 
        this.next = s; 
    }   
}
```

Y no entiendo por qué el atributo next es de tipo NodeInt. Quiero decir ¿Qué es next?.

---

pd:
El objetivo del código es crear una lista ordenada de datos mediante la creación de nodos que contienen el dato a guardar y una referencia al siguiente dato. Si el dato es el último, la referencia es `null`.

Comment: Para entender esa implementación, hay que repasar cómo funciona una lista enlazada.

Comment: Next es simplemente un objeto como el que estas definiendo.. es una definicion recursiva de una lista enlazada... deberias leer que es una lista enlazada como bien te escribieron arriba.

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Se puede crear un objeto antes de crear su constructor y además no guardar su referencia en ninguna variable?

Comment: todo lo que estas diciendo, no esta pasando en el codigo que muestras.. es justamente al reves...